# Forbidden (CSRF token missing)

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, csrf-token

I just learned how to create a web server on raspberry using django, i am trying to improve it by using JS that generates form every time i send data but am getting this error and haven’t found a solution yet. Need some help.

here the error when i run web server
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN3iS.png)

My html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>blablablai</title>
    <script>
        function sendDirection(direction) {
            const data = new FormData();
            data.append('direction', direction);
            const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open('POST', '{% url "home" %}');
            request.send(data);
        }
        
        function onMouseDown(direction) {
            sendDirection(direction);
        }
        
        function onMouseUp() {
            sendDirection('stop');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>bzzzz....</h1>

    <button type="button" onmousedown="onMouseDown('forward')" onmouseup="onMouseUp()">Forward</button>
    <button type="button" onmousedown="onMouseDown('backward')" onmouseup="onMouseUp()">Backward</button>
    <button type="button" onmousedown="onMouseDown('left')" onmouseup="onMouseUp()">Left</button>
    <button type="button" onmousedown="onMouseDown('right')" onmouseup="onMouseUp()">Right</button>

    <form method="post" action="{% url 'change_speed' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" name="speed" value="25">Speed 25%</button>
        <button type="submit" name="speed" value="50">Speed 50%</button>
        <button type="submit" name="speed" value="75">Speed 75%</button>
        <button type="submit" name="speed" value="100">Speed 100%</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import smbus

# Define I2C address
SLAVE_ADDRESS = 0x27

# Initialize I2C bus
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

# Define motor control functions
def forward():
    bus.write_byte(SLAVE_ADDRESS, ord('f'))

def backward():
    bus.write_byte(SLAVE_ADDRESS, ord('b'))

def turn_left():
    bus.write_byte(SLAVE_ADDRESS, ord('l'))

def turn_right():
    bus.write_byte(SLAVE_ADDRESS, ord('r'))

def stop():
    bus.write_byte(SLAVE_ADDRESS, ord('s'))
    
def speed25():
    bus.write_byte(SLAVE_ADDRESS, ord('1'))

def speed50():
    bus.write_byte(SLAVE_ADDRESS, ord('2'))

def speed75():
    bus.write_byte(SLAVE_ADDRESS, ord('3'))
    
def speed100():
    bus.write_byte(SLAVE_ADDRESS, ord('4'))
    
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        direction = request.POST.get('direction')
        speed = request.POST.get('speed')

        # Determine which button was pressed
        if direction == 'forward':
            forward()
        elif direction == 'backward':
            backward()
        elif direction == 'left':
            turn_left()
        elif direction == 'right':
            turn_right()
        elif direction == 'stop':
            stop()
    return render(request, 'home.html')
    
def change_speed(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        speed = request.POST.get('speed')

        # Determine which button was pressed
        if speed == '25':
            speed25()
        elif speed == '50':
            speed50()
        elif speed == '75':
            speed75()
        elif speed == '100':
            speed100()
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        return render(request, 'home.html')
```

I am new to Django, i have read and tried this documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/csrf/#using-csrf-protection-with-ajax but I cannot fix that. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs say you can set a request header.  Try

```
function sendDirection(direction) {
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('direction', direction);
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('POST', '{% url "home" %}');
  request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value))
  request.send(data);
}
```